# Disconnected space - Topology without tears exercise 3.3.3

Tags: general-topology

Prove $(X, \tau)$ is disconnected if and only if there exist sets $A, B \neq \emptyset $ with $A, B \in \tau$ such that $A\cup B = X$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

By disconnected I mean that there exists a clopen set that is not the $\emptyset$ or $X$.
From left to right it's quite easy. I'm having trouble with the other implication.

Comment: As you’ve written it, it isn’t true: the sets $A$ and $B$ have to be clopen (open and closed).

Comment: You should be a little bit more specific. What is your definition of connectedness? You have $A$ and $B$ written but it is unclear if they should be open or closed or arbitrary. Also, do you want $A\cup B=X$?

Also: if the statement were true as written any topological space having underlying set with cardinality $\ge 2$ would be disconnected...

Comment: Yes I will edit the post. Sorry

Comment: Hint: show $A = X \setminus B$, $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq X$.

Comment: @user854214 that is it! I knew it would have to look something like that but honestly, I’ve been studying for too long and nothing is making sense anymore. Thank you!! I can now go to sleep xd

Comment: Haha, sleep well. :-)